# How to split PDF into separate single page PDF in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

The requirement is to split the PDF in to individual page, retaining the individual file as .pdf extension only.
The files which are created in /CreatedPDF Folder are not getting opened [image]

Please help in figuring/correcting this issue.

```
//"fileURL" is the original File which has to be broken
//"pages" is the number of pages in PDF
NSInteger pages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDocReference);

for (int page = 1; page <= pages; page++)
 {
   NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSString *dirName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/CreatedPDF"];
   [fm createDirectoryAtPath:dirName withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
   NSString *pdfPath = [dirName stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page_%d.pdf",page]];
   NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];

   CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)pdfUrl, NULL, NULL);

   CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)fileURL);
   CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDoc, 1);
   CGRect pdfCropBoxRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);

   // Copy the page to the new document
   CGContextBeginPage(context, &pdfCropBoxRect);
   CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pdfPage);
   // Close the source files
   CGContextEndPage(context);
   CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDoc);
}
```

Comment: Can you add full code to extract the pages from a PDF? This will be helpful for the future readers starting with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i missed one line of code, as we have to release the CGContext also, so within the loop just add the line, rest all code will work.

```
CGContextRelease (context);
```