# Display PDF downloaded from URL according to individual pages

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, ipad, pdf

In my application I have requirement like displaying PDF according to pages.Only single page at a time with a Next & Previous buttons at bottom.On clicking "Next" will load the next page and so on...

I know that working with UIWebview we can display PDF, but the whole PDF document is displayed all at a time.Just need to display single page each time

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ExMonthly.pdf"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
wbView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
[wbView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:wbView];
```

this code displays all the available pages of that pdf.How can I get individual pages

Any ideas/help would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

Apple have QLPreviewController, but there is also whole pfd if I'm not mistaken. 
You can save the pdf, next split pdf to single pages ([for iOS see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992238/how-to-split-pdf-into-separate-single-page-pdf-in-ios-programmatically)), make a custom UIViewController with UIWebView and 2 buttons Next & Prev. Next just reload UIWebView to read each individual page.

Something like this:

```
- (void)savePdfDataLocally {
    NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ExMonthly.pdf"]];

    //Get path directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //Create PDF_Documents directory
    documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF_Documents"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"ExMonthly.pdf"];

    [dataPdf writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}

- (void)loadPage:(int)page {
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath_from_previous_function]];
    webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    [webView loadRequest:request];
} 

- (IBAction)nextTap:(id)sender {
   currentPage++;
   [self loadPage:currentPage];
}
```